# Filtering a dataframe in R based on multiple Conditions

Tags: r, filter

I am new  to using R. I am  trying to figure out how to create a df from an existing df that excludes specific participants. For example I am looking to exclude Women over 40 with high bp. I have tried several times to use the subset () but I cannot find a way to exclude using multiple criteria. Please Help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R, without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).

Answer (score 5):

Let df be the dataframe with at least three columns gender, age and bp.

The idea behind filtering is that it checks each entry against a condition and returns only the entries satisfying said condition.

Thus in the present case, it is enough to write:

```
df[!(df$gender == "woman" & df$age > 40 & df$bp = "high"), ]
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep other participants with varrying ages and bp. So for example if I have a df that includes both men and women with ages 20-80 and bp levels "low" "med" "high", I only want to exclude those participants who are women over 40 with bp score "high" how can I exclude those participants without excluding all women or all participants over 40

Comment: Assuming that you have a column labeled sex, then you would just have to add the corresponding condition. I ll edit the answer.